# suggest Free tools to monitor cassandra cluster performance

Tags: cassandra

I want to monitor cassandra cluster on CentOS machine. Suggest me Free tools to monitor performance in terms of discs, RAM, nodetool commands and other parameters.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Prometheus.io and the various exporters.

Here's a good blog on it: http://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-cassandra-with-prometheus/ .

In terms of the nodetool commands etc.. you would probably be worth automating things like this via tools like Ansible and/or Rundeck.

You can also have a look at axonops.com .

Answer (score 0):

There are many host side monitoring tools,

I personally use [Nmon](http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php) for a my host side monitoring of a cassandra cluster.
See also: [Installing NMon](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nmon-performance-analyzer-linux-server-tool/)

You can easily create graphs out of the nmon results using [NMONVisualizer](http://nmonvisualizer.github.io/nmonvisualizer/)